# How to generate non interfering SVGs (Cloud embedded)?

Tags: export, wolfram-cloud, conversion, svg-format

### The problem

Please run this in the Cloud:

```
StringJoin[
  ExportString[{},"SVG"]
, "<br>"
, ExportString[Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6}],"SVG"]
]//EmbeddedHTML
```

> [image]

Notice that x-axis 1 and 2 ticks were replaced with {}.

### Probable cause

That is because they they are referenced within svg with e.g.:

```html
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-2" x="130.22449" y="118.975691"></use>
```

and this `glyph0-2` id is defined in `<defs>` for both svgs. Since ids are supposed to be unique only the very first one found is used in both images.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

Do not know how general it is but works for me atm:

```
UniqueSVGExport[expr_]:= Module[{uniqueRef}
, uniqueRef[s_String]:=uniqueRef[s] = CreateUUID[s]
; ExportString[expr, "SVG"] // 
    StringReplace[
      g : ("glyph" ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "-" ~~ DigitCharacter ..) :> uniqueRef@g
    ]
]
```

> [image]